# Risk of using scripting language on backend?

Tags: web-application

If you are using a scripting language like for example Python for the back-end of a web-service, is there a risk connected to this which is not present if you would use a compiled language?

Take for example this pseudo-code:

```
password = request["password"]
if password == "abc123":
    print("Welcome.")
    #...
else:
    print("Wrong password.")
```

Couldn't someone who got access to your server alter the code to remove the check `password == "abc123"` so that no authentication is required anymore?

Of course you are already screwed when someone has access to your server, but isn't this an extra risk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main risk of scripting languages is that they usually have constructs to execute a string as code, i.e. things like `eval`. This can be used for injections attacks if this feature is used in the code together with user supplied input without sanitizing the input. But it is not that compiled code is immune to such kind of attacks: command injection and SQL injection work also in compiled code and code execution using buffer overflow is a code injection attack which is more typical for compiled code than for scripting languages.

> Couldn't someone who got access to your server alter the code to remove the check ...

That is not much different from simply replacing a compiled binary. It requires an understanding of the code and the ability to change it (i.e. write access).

> Of course you are already screwed when someone has access to your server, but isn't this an extra risk?

I would argue that this risk is not "extra", but that might still be part of the risk analysis, since it might make specific attacks easier compared to compiled languages. Similar one might argue though that it will be also easier for someone auditing the compromised system to detect what was changed and for what purpose.

Or in short: the impact of using a scripting language vs. compiled code really depends on the context of the broader system where it is used and can not be simply looked at in isolation.

Comment: Given the prominence of pre-baked malware kits, I'd say there's no real difference a scripted versus compiled program. Both can be overwritten with malicious versions with the same effort.